# Redmine Plugin Partials not being found

Tags: ruby, redmine, partials, redmine-plugins

I have been following the [Redmine Plugin Tutorial](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Tutorial) and read the page on [Hooks](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Hooks), but I still can't get my plugins partials to render, using the `render_on` keyword or otherwise.

Here's where I'm putting my partials:

```
app
└── views
    ├── issues
    │   └── _issue_mail_settings_form.html.erb
    └── projects
        └── _mail_settings_form.html.erb
```

Here is my class with the `render_on` keyword, which is in the `lib` directory:

```
class MailSettingIssueHooks < Redmine::Hook::ViewListener
  render_on :view_issues_form_details_bottom,            
      :partial => "issues/issue_mail_settings_form"                                                                                                
end
```

In init.rb I just `require 'mail_setting_issue_hooks'`.

If I load Redmine up like this, I can't view the page for any issues - I just get a 404 error. Console output for the request is [here](http://pastebin.com/DYPPATLf), though it doesn't look useful.

If I define a method named `view_issues_form_details_bottom` in `MailSettingIssueHooks` and it returns a string, that renders correctly.

**How does the `render_on` keyword decide where to look for partials, and how can I get it working?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When Redmine loads plugins, it adds the default views directory of each - `app/views` - to the global Rails view path. The catch is it does **not** use the actual directory on disk - it assumes a plugin is located `plugins/<name>`, where `<name>` is the argument you use to `Redmine::Plugin.register`.

This means that if your `init.rb` looks like:

```
Redmine::Plugin.register :cool_stuff do
...
```

But your plugin's directory is actually `redmine_cool_stuff`, the code will load and execute but the views will not be found.

**Solution:** Make sure the argument to `Plugin.register` is the same as the name of your directory in the redmine `plugins` directory.