# redmine-my-widgets-plugin not working on redmine 2.3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

The following is the repository for redmine.

https://github.com/redmine/redmine

And the following is the repository for redmine-my-widgets-plugin

if we look at the file structure app/views/my

https://github.com/redmine/redmine/tree/master/app/views/my

there is a folder blocks which contains the partial which are widgets and displayed when added from select list.

similarly for redmine-my-widgets-plugin there is similar file directory structure

https://github.com/bradbeattie/redmine-my-widgets-plugin/tree/master/app/views/my

when i install this plugin the partials mentioned in this /my/block gets added in the my page -> select list so as to be added

When we add one of the plugins select list value then it **displays 404 error**

By looking at the structure the plugin, it looks like the plugin is overrided.
Also there are no others config files, or lib files present in the plugin(except en.yml)

So, what can be done that the plugin will be able to atleast find those partials.

Basically, redmine is able to find the partial files as the names are displayed in the my page -> select list but when added it throws 404 error

Answer (score 0):

I know, I'm rather late to the party, but maybe this answer helps somebody else in the future.

The underlying problem was already covered at [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893819/redmine-plugin-partials-not-being-found). The plugin directory needs to have the exact same name as the symbol that is passed to `Redmine::Plugin.register`. In the case of this plugin: `redmine_my_widgets`. Changing the directory name will fix the 404.

On the other hand, the plugin was not updated for a long time and it is very likely, that most, if not all of the widgets, will no longer work because of changes to Redmine's internals.